# Can field name be different from setter and getter in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Hi I am new in Jersey and working on a piece of code, where the name of setter is defined differnt from its field name. I am confused if this is allowed and would actually work when sending and receiving json data over http. Please can someone please explain how getter and setter actually work in Jersey framework.

```
public class TestValue{
    private String myLists;

@JsonSafeHtml
public String getMyLists() {
    return myLists;
}

@JsonSafeHtml
public void setMyList(String myLists) {
    this.myLists = myLists;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes I did and it seems to be working thats why I am confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior is actually to look at the bean properties (the getters and setters). The field doesn't matter in this case. It is just a convention to have them named the same as the methods.

The getter is used for serialization (java to json). The `get` will be stripped from the method, and the first letter after is lowercased. This will be the resulting JSON property name.

```
getSomething()    =>  { "something": "value" }
getAnotherThing() =>  { "anotherThing": "value" }
```

Setters are used for *de*serialization (json to java). The `set` will be stripped, and the first letter after lowercased. This is the method name that will be looked up to match with the JSON property.

```
{ "something": "value" }  =>  setSomething(String somthing)

// The following leads to an error. It doen't follow the 
// casing rule where the first letter is lowercased
{ "Something": "value" }  =>  setSomething(String somthing)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually in my case for some reason it is actually working. In one of the rest call I am passing [ comments: value ] and it is updating the comments field.. even though name of setter function is getComment(String comments). I am wondering if the Jersey is smart enough to detect if setter is not defined and update the field value directly....

Comment: Is the field public?

Comment: private String comments;

Comment: I don't know, maybe that is the fallback behavior. It's not something I have ever really tested

Comment: Thanks anyway, i agree this is not a good programming practise.